# Sum all number values in one column where year of date in another column equals 2014?

Tags: excel, formula

I am using the following formula to sum all the number values in one column where the year of a date is `2014` in my other column.

Here's what I have so far but it isn't working and returns a zero value:

```
=SUMIF('Completed Tenders'!B:B,YEAR(2014),'Completed Tenders'!K:K)
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is YEAR(2014) which is the year for 2014 days from the first of Jan 1900. You're basically saying you want to sum all tenders from July sixth 1905.

Try this which will check for the datevalue being greater or equal to the start of the year and smaller or equal to the last day of the year:

```
=SUMIFS('Completed Tenders'!K:K,'Completed Tenders'!B:B, ">="&DATEVALUE("2014-01-01"), 'Completed Tenders'!B:B, "<="& DATEVALUE("2014-12-31"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use this code it says your formula contains an error, I am using excel 2010

Comment: There's an extra quote in `">="&"DATEVALUE("2014-01-01")`. It should be `">="&DATEVALUE("2014-01-01")`. Possibly better as `">="&DATE(2014, 1, 1)`.